# Convert varchar to Date, not work with AND in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table `Companies` which contains a column `UserDefined4` of type `nvarchar(100)`.

This column contains some text plus a date in the format `DD.MM.YYYY`

I want to select the records in the month of March and April 2014.

I am running this query,

```
SELECT 
    (Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10)) 
FROM   
    Companies
WHERE  
    (Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10) not like '%[^0-9.]%' 
    AND (Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10) not like '')) 
    AND (CONVERT(Date,Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10),104) >= '2014-03-01' 
         and 
         CONVERT(Date,Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10),104) <= '2014-04-30')
```

This query throws an error

> Error converting a string to a date and / or time.

I have checked one by one all the records and they contains date in proper format. The strange thing for me is that the same query runs if I put `OR` instead of `AND` in following part, in the same query:

```
(
         CONVERT(Date,Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10),104) >= '2014-03-01' 
          OR 
         CONVERT(Date,Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10),104) <= '2014-04-30'
)
```

I know, its not a wise decision to save date as a `NVarChar` but I have to work with this data. I am not the one who designed this database.

Comment: when you provide date in string format use ISO format 'yyyymmdd' so in place of '2014-03-01' use '20140301' and '20140430' instead of '2014-04-30'. That '2014-04-30' can cause the error and sql-server may assume use fortmat

Comment: I will test if column Companies.UserDefined4 actually contains valid datetime using IsDate function if this function returns 1 then valid date else invalid date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had similar problems in the past and they were all due to some of the columns not ending with the expected characters (dates in your case) and the "guard clauses" (in your case the 1st two conditions in the `WHERE`) not stopping the query engine from applying the "range conditions" (in your case, the last two conditions in the `WHERE`).

Note that I don't know exactly why that happens (maybe query optimization, no "short-circuit" evaluation or the order in that the evaluation occurs isn't what we expect -- this is me speculating), but I've noticed that if you store an intermediate result of the query (with only the "guard clauses" applied) in a temporary structure (a table variable for example) and then apply the "range clauses" to that interim result, it'll work.

For example, this will work even if there are "bad" rows (rows that don't end in a date):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (userdate CHAR(10))

INSERT @t
SELECT RIGHT(Companies.UserDefined4, 10)
FROM Companies
WHERE RIGHT(Companies.UserDefined4, 10) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
    AND RIGHT(Companies.UserDefined4, 10) <> ''

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, userdate, 104) >= '2014-03-01'
    AND CONVERT(DATE, userdate, 104) <= '2014-04-30'
```

You can check a fiddle demonstrating the issue [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e81a/10).

Answer (score 2):

Can you be **sure** that `UserDefined4` really **always** contains a date in that format in the right-most 10 characters?

If so, you could create a **computed column** like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Companies
ADD DateFromUD4 AS CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(UserDefined4, 10), 104) PERSISTED
```

and then the query becomes really simple:

```
SELECT 
    (list of columns)
FROM   
    dbo.Companies
WHERE  
    DateFromUD4 >= '20140301' AND 
    DateFromUD4 <= '20140430'
```

I like to use the **ISO-8601** format (`YYYYMMDD` without any dashes) for specifying dates as string since this is guaranteed to work on **any** SQL Server regardless of the date and language settings.

Since the conversion goes to a `DATE`, you won't have to worry about time portions either - this is a **date-only** computed column. This works in SQL Server **2008** and newer.